# Jqgrid sorting numeric order

Tags: model-view-controller, sorting, jqgrid

As far as I know sorting in jqgrid will be like this sortname: 'Key', sortorder: "asc", but everytime the 'Key' shows it's not in numeric order. It looks like:

Key

1

10

100

1000

1001

1002

My output needed:

Key

1

2

3

4

5

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a extract of your code might be usefull...
Try to specify the sorttype option to **int** in your colmodel http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

Comment: Hi @Kayasax I already try that a while ago. It looks like this:
{ name: 'Key', index: 'Key', width: 100, align: 'left', hidden: false, formatter: 'int' } and sorttype:'int'

Comment: did you try to use another name than Key (it might be reserved ?)

Comment: is it possible that there is extra space in the value ? can you share a link or the source code ? Did you try with another dataset? Are you running the last version of jqgrid?

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign the sorttype:'int' inside the specific colModel that you want sorted

for ex. { name: 'Key', index: 'Key', width: 100, align: 'left', hidden: false, sorttype:'int' }